# Democratized Priority Algorithm

Tags: javascript, sorting

My title might be technically incorrect but I figured it helps get this post going in the right direction.

I'm entering a product prioritization discussion where one of the exercises for the team is to individually sort a list of 50 items from highest priority to lowest priority. We'll then use this data to build the collective team priority to facilitate the discussion.

I am looking for an algorithm I can implement in javascript which will accept a multidimensional array representing the sorted list of each person and output a single array containing the collective democratized priority.

Example input

```
[
    ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task2'],
    ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
    ['task1','task4','task5','task3','task2'],
    ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task4'],
    ...
]
```

From an output perspective, I would expect a single array where the first item in the array is the highest collective priority item, the second item to be the second-highest collective priority item, etc.

Can you recommend a particular algorithm and an example implementation in javascript?

Comment: Assign each task a score based on where it appears in people's priorities, then sort the tasks based on them.

Comment: It sounds like you have a [ranked voting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting). There are many different algorithms for arriving at a result, and no, we cannot recommend one.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. It seems like Borda count may fit the need.

Answer (score 1):

Here I do some reverse-index scoring algorithm where most important tasks get more scores, check it

```js
// Set workers and individual tasks priority
const workers = [
    ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task6'],
    ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
    ['task1','task4','task5','task6','task2'],
    ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task6']
];

// Set common priority list object
const priority = {};

// For each worker
for(let i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
  const worker = workers[i];
  // Loop worker tasks
  for(let i = 0; i < worker.length; i++) {
    const task = worker[i];
    // No type, set it to 0
    if(!priority[task]) priority[task] = 0;
    // Alter each task type with
    // individual priority.
    //
    // Here I do some reverse-scoring algorithm
    // where most important tasks get more
    // scores
    priority[task] += workers.length - i;
  }
}

// Sort common priority list object by values
const sortedPriority = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(priority).sort(([key1,val1],[key2,val2]) => val2 - val1));

// Log sorted object with tasks and
// their priority scores
console.log(sortedPriority);
```

Next example pretty the same, but here I use exponential algorithm, so most important tasks get more scores exponentially. You can see here some differences in ranking of `task5` and `task3`

```js
// Set workers and individual tasks priority
const workers = [
    ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task6'],
    ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
    ['task1','task4','task5','task6','task2'],
    ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task6']
];

// Set common priority list object
const priority = {};

// For each worker
for(let i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
  const worker = workers[i];
  // Loop worker tasks
  for(let i = 0; i < worker.length; i++) {
    const task = worker[i];
    // No type, set it to 0
    if(!priority[task]) priority[task] = 0;
    // Alter each task type with
    // individual priority.
    //
    // Here I do exponential algorithm
    // where most important tasks get more
    // scores exponentially
    priority[task] = Number((priority[task] + Math.exp(workers.length - i)).toFixed(2));
  }
}

// Sort common priority list object by values
const sortedPriority = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(priority).sort(([key1,val1],[key2,val2]) => val2 - val1));

// Log sorted object with tasks and
// their priority scores
console.log(sortedPriority);
```

Comment: well, I says "kind of"... ok, thanx) I'll correct it now

Comment: Ok, I've added exponential algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve it:

```
var users = [ ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task6'],
  ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
  ['task1','task4','task5','task6','task2'],
  ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task6']];
var res = {};

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++) {
    var task = users[i][j];
    if(!res[task]) res[task] = 1;
    else res[task]++;
  }
}

var items = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
  return [key, res[key]];
});

items.sort(function(first, second) {
  return second[1] - first[1];
});

var final_res = items.map(function(item){return item[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the task lists for each user is already sorted, each individual task index from every list can be summed up and used as "cumulative priority". Just sort the tasks by that priority in ascending order and you're good to go.

```js
var taskLists = [
    ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task2'],
    ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
    ['task1','task4','task5','task3','task2'],
    ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task4'],
    // ...
];

var priorities = {};

for (let userTasks of taskLists) {
    for (let tI in userTasks) {
        var task = userTasks[tI];
        priorities[task] || (priorities[task] = 0);
        priorities[task] += ~~tI;
    }
}

var prioritized = Object.keys(priorities)
    .map((task) => [task, priorities[task]])
    .sort((a, b) =>a[1] - b[1])
    .map((i) => i[0]);

console.log(prioritized);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an exponential value for adding the ranks which keeps first voted items on top.

```js
var votes = [
        ['task1', 'task3', 'task5', 'task4', 'task2'],
        ['task4', 'task3', 'task5', 'task2', 'task1'],
        ['task1', 'task3', 'task5', 'task4', 'task2'],
        ['task5', 'task2', 'task3', 'task1', 'task4']
    ],
    sums = votes.reduce((r, ranks) => {
        ranks.forEach((v, i, { length }) => {
            if (!r[v]) r[v] = 0;
            r[v] += length ** (length - i - 1);
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a preferential voting problem with a [instant-runoff voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting), with a small twist of running multiple rounds.

The idea is to run multiple elections, the task who wins the *i-th* election is the *i-th* most prioritized.
In each election we consider the most important still electable task of every team-member.
If the most-voted task has more than half the votes, he have a winner. If isn't, we remove the less-voted task from this election and keep going.

Here's an implementation:

```js
const preferences = [
    ['task1','task3','task5','task4','task2'],
    ['task3','task1','task5','task2','task4'],
    ['task1','task4','task5','task3','task2'],
    ['task5','task2','task3','task1','task4'],
]
const halfVotes = Math.round(preferences.length / 2)

let remainingTasks = new Set(preferences[0])
let orderOfPreference = []

while (remainingTasks.size > 0) {
  let notSkipTasks = new Set(remainingTasks)
  let winner = null
  
  while (winner == null) {
    let lessVoted = null
    let loserOfRound = ""
    
    let count = new Map()
    preferences.map(tasks => tasks.filter(x => notSkipTasks.has(x))[0])
               .forEach(vote => count[vote] = (count[vote] || 0) + 1)
    
    for (let [vote, qtd] of Object.entries(count)) {
      if (qtd > halfVotes) {
        winner = vote
      }
      if ((lessVoted == null) || (qtd < count[lessVoted])) {
        lessVoted = vote
      }
    }
    notSkipTasks.delete(lessVoted)
  }
  
  orderOfPreference.push(winner)
  remainingTasks.delete(winner)
}
console.log(orderOfPreference)
```

It's worth to mention that this method isn't targeted for small groups, so it have no general tie-breaking rule for the less-voted.